# Partial rendered with AJAX not working correctly

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

I render this partial with AJAX:

```
<% if current_user.profiles_shown_video.where("video_id = ?", params[:id]).count == 0 %>
  <p class="none"> None </p>
<% else %>
  <ul class="shown_users_list">
    <% current_user.profiles_shown_video.where("video_id = ?", params[:id]).each do |p| %>  
      <li><%= link_to image_tag(p.photo.url(:thumbnail)), profile_path(p), :class => "feed_image"%> 
          <%= link_to "#{p.user.name}", profile_path(p), :class => "normal squeeze" %> 
          <%= link_to image_tag("/images/facebox/closelabel.gif"), showable_video_path(ShowableVideo.find_by_user_id_and_profile_id_and_video_id(current_user, p, @video)), :method => :delete, :remote => true, :class => "showable_video_delete" %></li>
    <% end %>
  </ul> 
<% end %>
```

For some reason, the first if statement is always being evaluated to true, even if it shouldn't be. In other words, `<p class="none"> None </p>` is always being displayed. If I refresh the page, it gets corrected. Why is the if statement of this partial not being evaluated correctly when rendered with AJAX? How can I fix this?

Here's the destroy action:

```
def destroy
  @showable_video = current_user.showable_videos.find(params[:id])
  @showable_video.destroy
  respond_to do |format|
     format.html {redirect_to :back}
     format.js
   end
end
```

This is in destroy.js.erb. It renders a partial containing the first block of code above:

```
$("#shown_users_div").html('<%= escape_javascript(render("showable_videos/shown_users")) %>')
```

Comment: More context is needed. What code is running in your ajax action?

Answer (score 0):

ActiveRecord caches associated objects. After running `@showable_video.destroy`, `current_user` (itself probably being cached) will still have `@showable_video` in memory, so the collection will be non-empty. After creating, updating, or deleting the database record, you must run:

```
current_user.reload
```

so that it reloads associated objects from the database.

Comment: no, the problem is that `current_user.profiles_shown_video.where("video_id = ?", params[:id]).count` is always being evaluated to 0 when it actually shouldn't be, not that the collection is still non-empty.

Comment: Sorry, I'm just guessing. I don't know what the `profiles_shown_video` method is and I don't know what columns/associations are on your models.

Comment: It's ok. I was thinking that it might have something to with AJAX in general as opposed to the specifics of my app.

Comment: @user730569 Now that someone has downvoted my answer, are you going to post what the code for `profiles_shown_video` or your models so I can have a chance to redeem myself?